# np.concatenate won't concatenate

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to concatenate those 2 matrices 'Y' and 'I' but I can't understand what's wrong.
I took a black and white image and got the matrices 'Y', 'I' and 'Q', did some changes on the values of them and want to put them back together using 'np.concatenate()':

```
Y = imYIQ[:, :, 0]
I = imYIQ[:, :, 1]
Q = imYIQ[:, :, 2]

normalized_Y = np.true_divide(Y, np.max(Y))

# Normalizes to [0, 1], stretches to [0, 2] and moves to the left to [-1, 1] both of 'I' and 'Q'
normalized_I = np.subtract(np.multiply(np.true_divide(I, np.max(I)), 2), 1)
normalized_Q = np.subtract(np.multiply(np.true_divide(Q, np.max(I)), 2), 1)

# Code crashes here:
concatenatedYI = np.concatenate(normalized_Y, normalized_I, axis=0)
```

The error that I get is:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Does anyone understand what does this error mean in this context?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `np.concatenate()` is a sequence:

`np.concatenate([normalized_Y, normalized_I], axis=0)`

See: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

Comment: If this solved your question please accept the answer so it doesn't show in open questions. Thanks!